# seting universal spawn prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static-members

we've been banging our heads with this one, in theory, having a public static object to hold the prefab which is to be spawned should have solved this, but the script gets a static variable when the static keyword is not there, but still the objects get individual variables, while when I add the static keyword, the script's variable disappears. Are we doing something wrong? This is the exact definition:

```
public static Object prefab;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too am still new with Unity, but will offer some personal research / findings.  I too hate to explicitly have some object with public properties exposed so you can "stick" an object prefab in a scene.  If trying to build a system / game components dynamically, knowing what / when to add would be your discretion.  I too liked the approach of having a STATIC available so you can just go to it at any time you needed another "thing".

I found that using "Resources" could allow you to load a prefab via code without the need of having a scene object to drag controls to, such as for a master list.

In you default "Assets" folder, Create a folder "Resources" (not sure if case-sensitive).  Anyhow, I put all my other stuff in respective folders under that... materials, prefabs, sprites, textures, whatever...  So now, in my "Prefab" folder, I could have a prefab for a "Hero", "Laser", "Shield", whatever.

Now, how to get these pieces into your STATIC class.  You could create a special method that you call to just load them via the resources class of Unity, then, create function that will return a CLONE of the item in question.  This way, you leave the original alone, and have your own to work with in your game as needed.

Something like...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace Assets.Scripts
{
    public static class MyGameObjManager 
    {
        private static bool alreadyLoaded;
        public static GameObject myHero { get; private set; }
        public static GameObject myWeapon {get; private set;}

        public static void LoadObjects()
        {
            if (alreadyLoaded)
                return;

            // Load the resource which is RELATIVE to the "Resources" path...
            myHero = (GameObject)Resources.Load("Prefab/Hero");

            // This OTHER appears to load at a SPECIFIC Path allowing it to go to the root level ASSETS
            myWeapon = (GameObject)Resources.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Resources/Prefab/Weapon", typeof(GameObject));

            alreadyLoaded = true;
        }

    }

    public class GameMgr2 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static GameObject GetHero()
        {
            MyGameObjManager.LoadObjects();
            return (GameObject)Instantiate(MyGameObjManager.myHero, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Quaternion());
        }

        public static GameObject GetWeapon()
        {
            MyGameObjManager.LoadObjects();
            return (GameObject)Instantiate(MyGameObjManager.myWeapon, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Quaternion());
        }
    }
}
```

So, the STATIC class CAN NOT derive from MonoBehavior which allows the "Instantiate" call to create the clone of the object and return it.  So, I created a SECONDARY non-static class that IS derived from MonoBehavior and put static methods that call the static game object manager to get the prefabs I need.

AGAIN, I too am still learning, but hope this helps you some with your design considerations...  As for the calling to get the hero or weapon, you could obviously parameterize it by passing in its Vector3 coordinate, or Quaternion value, but you can run with it.

STATIC vs NOT

Per your code and making it a STATIC means a single instance no matter how many of the class are put anywhere within the system.  So if you have 5 prefabs on a screen and try to put each one to a different "thing", it will overwrite with whatever one was assigned last.  Having the property as just "public" will allow you to have 5 prefabs on a screen and then drag/drop different "things" on each respectively and each will retain their own "thing" instance.

Sorry I can't advise more without knowing what you are trying to implement.

non-static should help within the editor by drag/drop.  However, STATIC

Comment: Trying it out as we speak, just a suggestion in the meantime, you can use Quaternion.Identity in the Instantiate method, in XNA and I believe in Unity too it's the default parameter everyone uses when coming across quaternions

Comment: Well, it seems to work, though it says everything is null, I guess it's just till I figure what is what in there

Comment: Ok, it worked when I placed in in Resources and with Load(), with LoadAssetAtPath, and with subfolders in Resources it did not make it.. But I'm just glad I managed to get something working in under two weeks in Unity, so thanks a million! I cannot unfortunately tick the answer since it does not exactly answer the weird side effects, even though it works..

Comment: @user3079666,  The side effect of the "static" is due to a single instance.  When you want to create multiple from a baseline, you need to do the "Instantiate" which IS part of the answer and doesn't create new variables for you.

Comment: Hold on. I declared it static in the script, and then I tossed the script into a prefab, and dragged that into the scene, in fact a teammate made 70 instances in the editor by copy-paste, however they all have the field as if it were a non-static variable.. Shouldn't the editor handle that? I mean, people use game engines with editors so they do not instantiate items through code and programmatically position them, what's the point to that if static variables mess it up?

Comment: @user3079666, see revised note about STATIC vs NOT

Comment: @user3079666, oh my god about what... your overall intended implementation?  Or what I presented?

Comment: About unity, it is inconceivable to me that any tool would allow you to modify static variables as if non-static and show you a bunch of different versions of the variable, other than misrepresenting the variable, it leads to chaos and confusion. Anyway, problem solved, so that will be all, again thank you very much, I doubt I'd have figured that out any time soon.